# UDP order of bytes in a packet

Tags: networking, udp

I am working on a application where a couple of clients are streaming audio to a Rasbperry PI via UDP. From other topics I understand that the order of the packets send via UDP are not guaranteed to arrive in the same order.
But how about the bytes in a packet, can I assume these will arrive in the same order then that they are send by the sender?

I want to embed some status information of the sender into a package, can I use lets say the first couple of bytes of the package to do this? In this case I need to be sure that these bytes are on the same position at the sender and receiver.
And is this a good approach to follow?

Comment: What you really need to do is create an application-layer protocol. That is what is done with VoIP, HTTP, etc. Your application can then use this protocol to drop out-of-order packets. With audio, you cannot afford to take the time to reorder packets, and you really don't want to use packets that arrive after they are useful. There are several protocols used by various VoIP implementations to do this for you, or you can roll your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of bytes in an UDP packet is left unchanged. While UDP is not a reliable protocol the duplicates, reordering or packet loss happen only for whole packets but not for single bytes inside a packet.